# os.system calls run like serial execution multi-threads

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, system-calls

My co-worker asked me why his code cannot run in concurrency in multi-threads. I discover the `os.system` function is acting weird unlike the other functions in multi-threads. I code a small demo to reproduce the problem. Appreciating somebody who can answer my question.

### Run like serial execution

```py
import os
import time

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
begin = time.time()

for _ in as_completed([
        executor.submit(os.system, cmd)
        for cmd in ['sleep 10', 'sleep 3', 'sleep 2']
    ]):
    print("completed after", time.time() - begin, "seconds")
```

output

```
completed after 10.005892276763916 seconds
completed after 13.017478942871094 seconds
completed after 15.034425258636475 seconds
```

### Run normally

Replace `os.system` with `subprocess.call`.

```py
import subprocess
import time

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
begin = time.time()

for _ in as_completed([
        executor.submit(subprocess.call, cmd, shell=True)
        for cmd in ['sleep 10', 'sleep 3', 'sleep 2']
    ]):
    print("completed after", time.time() - begin, "seconds")
```

output

```
completed after 2.019604206085205 seconds
completed after 3.017033338546753 seconds
completed after 10.009897232055664 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

[`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is implemented by calling the standard C function `system`:

> This is implemented by calling the Standard C function `system()`, and
> has the same limitations.

And according to the man page of the [`system`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3p.html) function:

> Blocking `SIGCHLD` while waiting for the child to terminate prevents the
> application from catching the signal and obtaining status from
> `system()`'s child process before `system()` can get the status itself.

and:

> Using the `system()` function in more than one thread in a process or
> when the `SIGCHLD` signal is being manipulated by more than one thread
> in a process may produce unexpected results.

Since `SIGCHLD` must be blocked during the execution, calling `system` concurrently would not work.

[`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) (the underlying class that the `subprocess.call` function uses) on the other hand handles `fork`/`exec`/`wait` without blocking `SIGCHLD` and can therefore be executed concurrently.